# How can I copy and paste code to an emtpy file in the vim editor?

Tags: vim, terminal

I want to replace a file with another file I have written in a text editor. I have cleared the current file in the vim editor, but when I try to paste my new code into the empty file, it does not let me do so. How can I paste into the vim editor?

Comment: Do `$ vimtutor`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're in the scratchpad of vim.. Make sure you get into the file first.

Starting from the command line:

```
vim path/to/my_file.txt
:set paste
i
<Paste your code here>
<Hit the escape key>
:w
:q
```

If vim is already open:

```
:e path/to/my_file.txt
:set paste
i
<Paste your code here>
<Hit the escape key>
:w
:q
```